# find out what functions are used inside object file functions

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, elf

Let's say I have linux kernel module with two functions

`function A` which calls `function c` from the kernel

`function B` which calls `function d` from the kernel

Now if I pass the object file of this module through tools like `readelf` and `nm` I can see the symbols used in the binary but what I want to know is which function is used inside which function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what I want to know is which function is used inside which function

```
objdump -dr kernel_module.ko
```

will show you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try `gdb`. 
It's a text based debugger with which you could analyze and investigate your binary.

First find out about the entry point address of the binary:

```
readelf -h my-binary | grep "Entry point"
```

Then fire up gdb with the binary loaded into it:

```
gdb my-binary
```

Now use the entry point you've got from readelf to make a breakpoint in the execution of my_binary in order to be able to analyze it.

```
break * [address from readlf]
```

Run the gdb and hit the breakpoint.

```
run
```

Now you can actually go ahead and investigate the functions by running:

```
info functions
```